# What does "Alice started to her feet" mean?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

In the book *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*, what does “Alice started to her feet” mean?

> ... But when the rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, **Alice started to her feet**...

Comment: In modern English, _start_ doesn't mean 'jump up in surprise' nearly as often as it might have in the 19th century. Nowadays, _start_ has become almost entirely a marker of beginnings: _start your engines/your homework/going there regularly/smoking cannabis_, etc. Much like _stop_, and in parallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means she suddenly stood up or jumped to her feet, probably in amazement.

**EDIT**

According to the OED, *start* could mean:

> **3** [ no obj. ] jerk or give a small jump from surprise or alarm: *‘Oh my!’ she said, starting.*
>   • [ no obj., with adverbial of direction ] literary move or appear suddenly: *she had seen Meg start suddenly from a thicket.*

Answer (score 2):

The closest meaning in the *OED* for the verb *start* is 2b: "To spring *on, upon one's feet*."

> - c1420   Lydgate *Assembly of Gods* 566   Than Pheb[e] styrt vppon her fete And seyd [etc.].
> - c1540  (1400)    *Destr. Troy* 10977   And ho stithly in the stoure start vppon fote.
> - a1600   A. Montgomerie *Misc. Poems* xxxiii. 21   Vpon my feet incontinent I start.
> - 1847   Tennyson *Princess* i. 59   He started on his feet.

This [Ngram chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=started+to+his+feet%2Cstarted+to+her+feet%2Cstarted+to+my+feet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) suggests this particular use is now somewhat dated, and although I understand the text from the context, it's not something I'd use in everyday speech, or can recall hearing either.

[image: start to (someone's) feet appears to take off around 1820, peaks around 1880 and has mostly declined by around 1940]

Answer (score 0):

The expression *got to her feet* (or *rose to her feet*) means that the person stood upright (from either a sitting or lying position). To *start* in this context means a sudden but usually small movement.

So **started to her feet** means that Alice stood up quickly without any prior movement indicating that she would do so.

Look at [this photograph](http://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/2010717933/) with the title *He is here! suddenly cried Dolly, and started to her feet* made by the artist W T Smedley. It captures the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of the phrase saying *Alice started to her feet*: the girl had no intention of moving from where she had sat but she suddenly moved at the rabbit's appearance towards her.

Therefore, this phrase means suddenly stood upright and made a move.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).